# Eclipse Subversive: deleting repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I was working in Eclipse and used Subversive for versioning my program. However, now I would like to stop using SVN. Can I somehow delete repository from Eclipse i.e., not to synchronize any more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could disconnect (right click on project -> Team -> Disconnect) all your SVN projects and then open SVN repository explorer and remove (Discard location) SVN location. For doing it all your SVN projects have to be disconnected first.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way would be to delete all the .svn files in those directories. That is how Eclipse knows.